# How to create an ImageButton with an overlayed image?

Tags: android, android-widget, imagebutton

I have a button that starts out as a placeholder, but once the user authenticates, it changes to a custom image for that user.

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/button"
             android:background="@null"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:src="@drawable/button_default"/>
```

And then later:

```
ImageButton ib = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.button);
ib.setImageBitmap(previouslyDecodedBitmap);
```

But this looks terrible.  I can't figure out how to style it properly so that the newly decoded bitmap is the right size and behaves like an `ImageButton`.  I suspect there is some combination of widgets I can use other than `ImageButton` to achieve this?  I was hoping I could just nest an `ImageView` on top of the `ImageButton` by adding it as a child to `ImageButton`, but that doesn't seem to be allowed (it is in Silverlight...).

Anyway, any suggestions on how to properly do this are welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use frame layout and place buttons and image one over the other , top being imageview , keep it invisible (android:visibility = "invisible")
On clicking the button and authenticating , make it visible over the button or else even you can hide the button below and show only image on top.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up doing.  Thanks.